# Dialog not showing in android

Tags: codenameone

I call a simple Dialog.show("Notification", value)

When it is called on android it is not showing and i am receiving an error.

```
[EDT] 0:0:36,628 - Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Rows and columns must be greater than zero
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rows and columns must be greater than zero

I don't know what to do how to fix it ?

Comment: Got the answer basically the show must have at least on label for button and can't be call without four arguments minimum

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer basically the show must have at least on label for button and can't be call without four arguments minimum.

```
Dialog.show("Notification", bodyOfNotification, "OK", null));
```